# Select with chip input not displaying the selected value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Select and the inputs are in Chip Format. I tried console log of the value selected and it is getting it fine. But for some reason, it does not get displayed on the select box. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ badge : event.target.value });
  };

 const chipOptions = [
      {key: 1, 'text': 'text1',  'value': 'text1'},
      {key: 2, 'text':'text2', 'value':'text2'},
      {key: 3, 'text':'text3', 'value':'text3'}
    ]

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <Select
              value={this.state.badge}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              inputProps={{
                name: 'badge',
                id: 'badge-simple',
              }}
            >
            {chipOptions && chipOptions.map(option=> (
              <Chip key={option.value} label={option.value} className={classes.chip} value={option.value} />
            ))}

          </Select>
        </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default manner in which `Select` renders the selected value is to render its children. In the [Select source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L244) as it is looping through the children of the Select, it does the following:

```
        selected = areEqualValues(value, child.props.value);
        if (selected && computeDisplay) {
          displaySingle = child.props.children;
        }
```

This is based on the assumption of the `Select` having `MenuItem` children. For instance, in the following example the first MenuItem would be selected and that MenuItem's children would be the text "Item 1":

```
<Select value={1}>
   <MenuItem value={1}>Item 1</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value={2}>Item 2</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Your Chips don't have children, so nothing is displayed. You can customize this behavior by specifying the `renderValue` property on `Select`. This is a function that receives the value and can decide what to render.

The following example shows using the `renderValue` prop to render a `Chip`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    minWidth: 120
  }
});
const chipOptions = [
  { key: 1, text: "text1", value: "text1" },
  { key: 2, text: "text2", value: "text2" },
  { key: 3, text: "text3", value: "text3" }
];

function App({ classes }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("text1");
  const renderChip = value => {
    return <Chip label={value} className={classes.chip} />;
  };
  return (
    <>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <Select
          inputProps={{
            name: "badge",
            id: "badge-simple"
          }}
          renderValue={renderChip}
          value={value}
          onChange={event => {
            console.log(event.target.value);
            setValue(event.target.value);
          }}
        >
          {chipOptions &&
            chipOptions.map(option => (
              <Chip
                key={option.value}
                label={option.value}
                className={classes.chip}
                value={option.value}
              />
            ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
}
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Chip Select]

Comment: Great..! @Ryan  But in my case I need to POST the value in Payload and Display items in front-end with multiselect.

Comment: @Lee I recommend that you create a separate question where you can explain your problem more fully.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942512/post-selected-value-in-request-payload-and-display-list-of-items-in-front-end)